# Karate Embedded Expression not working as expected for xml attribute

Tags: xml, karate

This is : 3_PostData_Request.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Body>
        <SucceededGetData RequestID="#(request_uuid)">some text</SucceededGetData>
        <MessageDelivered OfferID="#(request_uuid)" />

    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

This is the scenario file:

```js
Scenario: test
    * def UUID = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() }
    * def request_uuid = call UUID
    * def req = read('classpath:3_PostData_Request.xml')
    * print req
```

This is the result:

```js
<S:Body>
    <SucceededGetData RequestID="ab5bbb38-d462-42f5-afd2-49c47fd59365">some text</SucceededGetData>
    <MessageDelivered OfferID="#(request_uuid)"/>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I would like to know why is this so happening. Why Karate is able to replace #(request_uuid) for xml element which has some text in it and why not for one without any text. How may I achieve replacement in both the cases seamlessely. I am using karate 0.7.0.1. Thanks !

I have added an issue in their Git repo as well. Waiting for reply from them. https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is a bug ! You have a workaround:

```
* set response /Envelope/Body/MessageDelivered/@OfferID = request_uuid
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for the quick response. The workaround solves my problem, however I wanted to avoid writing xpath in my scenario. No worries, I saw you fixed the issue in 0.7.1 version. Will wait for it to be available in maven. 

Also for others help, there is one more workaround I used:
In scenarioFile:
* replace req.${request_uuid} = request_uuid
And in xml I changed :
OfferID="#(request_uuid)" to OfferID="${request_uuid}"